# "text-align: center" with "text-overflow: ellipsis" not working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, ellipsis, gecko, blink

I have a horizontal list with ...-truncated titles which I want to be centered.

The centering works in Safari (top), but not in Chrome (bottom):

[image: Safari (good):]

[image: Chrome (bad):]

```css
ul {
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  display: block;
}


div {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid red;  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      IIIIMMM
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      MMMM
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Problem can be simplified as

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  width: 7em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>a⸻b…</div>
<div>a⸻b⸻c</div>
<p>Both <code>div</code>s should be identical.</p>
```

Rendered outcome in Chrome and Firefox:

[image]

Comment: Chrome might be thinking: if the content overflows and its truncating with '...' there is no centering, because the content is using the whole space - else it wouldn't be overflowing. 
hint: if you use 100% width on your div, the border is added to that, so your divs take more space than available.

Comment: Interesting problem, FWIV it is probably a bug in Chromium (Blink) and Firefox (Gecko) implementations. I took the liberty and added simplified test-case and added Firefox as affected browser, I think it describes your problem slightly better than initial one; if you agree you can remove that one.